# How to determine if resolved ip is rogue or part of CDN?

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing

I'm subscribed to goverment's owned ISP because only this ISP provides access to rural area.  It has a bad reputation because it is not only redirects sites, but  also injects JavaScript for advertising at the end of HTML pages.

I've been using dnscrypt to avoid redirection.  But a few hours ago, I accidentally discovered that DNS request for `www.google.com` resolved to `118.98.111.30`.  I'm using OpenDNS as a provider for `dnscrypt-proxy`.

A quick `whois` shows that the IP is owned by my ISP.  After restarting my home routers and PCs, DNS requests for `www.google.com` return IP owned by Google and never return `118.98.111.30` again.

I would like to know what I can do to determine that this IP is part of Google's CDN or some kind of rogue site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have hit the ["Google Global Cache"](https://peering.google.com/about/ggc.html) where servers are placed on your ISPs network to provide lower-latency access to commonly used resources.  The fact that visiting that IP address in a browser gives the Google search page reinforces this likelihood.

As for trusting IP addresses: don't.  Always use protocols protected by strong end-to-end encryption (TLS) and rely on the certificates presented.  While they might not be perfect (they're not!), the TLS infrastructure is a lot better than trying to be reassured about DNS.  (Though `dnscrypt` and/or `DNSSEC` can offer some reassurances in the DNS space as well, they're not widely deployed.)

Answer (score 2):

This ip, when accessed through https, provides a valid certificate for Google.com, so either this server is managed by Google or the ISP is doing a passthrough for HTTPS. Given that it serves a google certificate when accessing by ip, I lean towards it being a Google server.

In both cases, using https will ensure that you are communicating with the real Google¹ no matter if they are proxying your DNS or not.

Note that even if they don't poison your DNS, they can still snoop and modify all your http: pages, so you always need the https layer.

¹ I am assuming your ISP hasn't compromised a Google certificate and uses that to MiTM its customers :)

Answer (score 0):

When you aren't sure you can trust your ISP, use [the HTTPS version of google](https://google.com). When they try to redirect your request to a fake site, you will get a warning that the certificate isn't valid.

You should in fact do this for any website. The browser extension [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) can help you with this. It automatically redirects you to the HTTPS version of a website when available. Using HTTPS also prevents any code injection, by the way.